# MS Access ODBC VBA Refresh Links

Tags: ms-access, vba, quickbooks

I have an MS Access database with six (6) ODBC tables from Intuit QuickBooks Enterprise.  I created the links manually, and they worked fine right off the bat. However, the links need to be refreshed daily.  I attempted to write a VBA code to automate this process, however using `tdf.RefreshLinks` always failed.  I always have to manually refresh the links.  I discovered that the database name changes daily.  Once it's refreshed, it's refreshed the rest of the day no matter if the PC is restarted or not.  However, the next day the name is always different.  This must be something that QuickBooks does.  I think I need to be able to "grab" this database name in order to make my code work successfully. Has anyone ever heard of this?  Does anyone know how to overcome this so that I can script the refreshing of the links, instead of manually refreshing them?

Since I have no reputation on this site, I am unable to post any images.  But I can explain that my MSysObjects query shows the QuickBooks linked tables database name to be 33c292ce6be44bdca0cc8dd6c68594a0 and when I go to create a new link manually, the Connect to SQL Anywhere dialog box reveals on the Database tab the new day's database name: 4b2444e2c7ff4c37aa53d12a648f2fa0.  I know once I refresh the links, this will be the database name that shows up in my MSysObjects query for the rest of the day.  How do I get this so I can incorporate into VBA code? If this is truly the answer to automating the refreshing of the links?

Answer (score 0):

RefreshLink should work fine:

```
Dim db As DAO.Database, tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection ' cnn as in connection
On Error Resume Next
cnn.Open YOURCONNECTIONSTRINGHERE

Set db = CurrentDb

For each tdf in db.TableDefs
    tdf.Connect = YOURCONNECTIONSTRINGHERE
    tdf.RefreshLink
Next tdf

db.Close
Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation on .RefreshLink.  Wouldn't the connection string need to be able to obtain the new database name?  It isn't static, as I described in my original post, which prob explains the need to be refreshed.  I was thinking there might be a way to obtain this database name using VBA so my connection string would then be valid.  My other idea is to look at the driver provided by Intuit (for QuickBooks) to see if I have proper access to the QB database, to make sure I'm not blocked for some reason.